# trying to chain http requests together and return the final output as an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

While working in Typescript, i was having some issues with chaining observables together such that it made sense.   So in this sample i wrote up, i a condition which will depending its value, will either execute a function or do some preprocessing before executing the function.

When doing this I was noticing that the problem area is attempting to return an `Observable<Observable<number>>` which isnt what I was aiming for.  My thought was to return the inner value, but i was not sure how really to process this.

```
b(data: number): Observable<number> { return of(data); }  // This is a stub.
a(data: number): Observable<number> {

  const fn = (x): Observable<number> => {
    return of(x)  // this is a stub which would be the result of an http request.
  }

  if(data < 3) {
    return fn(data);
  } else {
    return b(data).pipe(map( x => fn(x) )) // Problem line
  }
}
```

How is this suppose to be processed?  I was thinking that there might be a way to handle this using a Promise, but I thought that would mess with the function signatures as I would need to label them as async.  I am stumped and would love some guidance.

Comment: Instead of a map, try a switchMap. In a map you want to return a value, you are returning an Observable there..

Comment: so you think: `return b(data).pipe(switchMap( x => fn(x)))` it certainly seems like the intellisense is no longer freaking out. let me test it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is one condition returns an observable, while the other returns an observable that returns an observable.  You should use one of the flattening operators such as *switchMap*, *concatMap*, or *mergeMap*.

```
return b(data).pipe(switchMap(x => fn(x)))
```

Maybe this could also benefit from a redesign?  Instead having two separate returns, create a stream from the result of the conditional statement a pipe it to the function.  This way you don't have to define a function just so you can use it in two places.

```
b(data: number): Observable<number> { return of(data); }  // This is a stub.
a(data: number): Observable<number> {
  const src$ = data < 3 ? of(data) : b(data);
  return src$.pipe(switchMap(x => of(x) /* your stub function */));
);
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to do things. I forgot about switchmap.